# How to apply mask to live camera in android opencv

Tags: opencv, camera, mask, android

I'm detecting blue color from live camera feed by using Core.inRange after getting the mask i.e imgThresholded when I take bitwise_and it shows the overlaping frames ,How can I get only one frame ?
[Frames are ovelaping for the detected object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8FiFb.png)

Here is my Code:

```
public Mat onCameraFrame(CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {       

     Imgproc.cvtColor(inputFrame.rgba(),imgHSV,Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2HSV);
          Core.inRange(imgHSV,new Scalar(100, 100, 100), new Scalar(120, 255, 
          255),imgThresholded); // Blue Color  
   Core.bitwise_and(inputFrame.rgba(),inputFrame.rgba(),tempImg,imgThresholded);
        return tempImg;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems, that is because you didn't clear `tempImg` `Mat` and use "old" content many times. Try add `tempImg.setTo(new Scalar(0,0,0,255))` to `onCameraFrame()`. Something like that:

```
public Mat onCameraFrame(CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {       

   tempImg.setTo(new Scalar(0,0,0,255));

   Imgproc.cvtColor(inputFrame.rgba(),imgHSV,Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2HSV);
          Core.inRange(imgHSV,new Scalar(100, 100, 100), new Scalar(120, 255, 
          255),imgThresholded); // Blue Color  
   Core.bitwise_and(inputFrame.rgba(),inputFrame.rgba(),tempImg,imgThresholded);
        return tempImg;
}
```